# Build list of values from rows in one table ordered by relationships in a different table

Tags: sql-server

Consider the following tables:

Applications

```
+----+-------------+---------+----------+
| id | previous_id | next_id | status   |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+
| 1  |   NULL      |    3    | Archived |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+
| 3  |     1       |    4    | Archived |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+
| 4  |     3       |   NULL  | Approved |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+
```

Comments

```
+-----+--------+----------------+
| id  | app_id |   comment      |
+-----+--------+----------------+
|  1  |   1    |  Testing       |
+-----+--------+----------------+
|  2  |   1    |  Still testing |
+-----+--------+----------------+
|  3  |   4    |  No longer     |
+-----+--------+----------------+
```

The Applications table contains revisions of an application.  The comments table contains comments that were left on each iteration of the application.  They are tied together via:

```
Applications.ID = Comments.APP_ID
```

There is a breadcrumb that will tell you if there were any previous revisions to the application, and if you are dealing with the current one or not (the current row will always have NULL as the next_id value.

I want to build two things.

1. A count of how many revisions an application has had.  It may be zero revisions, or it may be 16+.
2. A list of comments for any given current application (like ID = 4) and all previous applications, ordered newest comment to oldest comment.

Comment: That's nice, and what you have now?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin.  I suspect it can be done purely in SQL, but anything I did would be a weird combination of ColdFusion and SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE, you can build a list of revisions for any given application. The following query will give you a list of revision/comments, ordered by revision (newest first), and comment id (newest first), separated by base application. There is an extra count column `revision_count` duplicated for each row, so this is all done in one query. Note the revision count is 0-based; that is, the count is the number of revisions to the base, *not including* the base. I believe this is what you want. The result column `revision` is the 1-based revision number (1 is the oldest, base revision) in the sequence.

You can of course extrapolate or adjust as necessary.

```
;WITH Base AS
(
    SELECT id, next_id, status, 1 AS revision
    FROM Applications
    WHERE previous_id IS NULL
), Revisions AS
(
   SELECT id, next_id, status, revision, id AS BASEID
   FROM Base
   UNION ALL
   SELECT a.id, a.next_id, a.status, r.revision + 1 AS revision, r.BASEID
   FROM Applications a
   INNER JOIN Revisions r ON a.id = r.next_id
), RevisionCounts AS
(
   SELECT COUNT(1) - 1 AS revision_count, BASEID
   FROM Revisions
   GROUP BY BASEID
)
SELECT r.BASEID, r.revision, r.id, r.status, c.comment, rc.revision_count
FROM Revisions r
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments c ON c.app_id = r.id
INNER JOIN RevisionCounts rc ON r.BASEID = rc.BASEID
ORDER BY r.BASEID, r.revision DESC, c.id DESC
```

And [here is a fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2386/6) to go along with it, demonstrating the query in action. The returned data is:

```
BASEID  REVISION    ID  STATUS      COMMENT         REVISION_COUNT
1       3           4   Approved    No longer       2
1       2           3   Archived    (null)          2
1       1           1   Archived    Still testing   2
1       1           1   Archived    Testing         2
```

Comment: You're welcome. For anyone wanting to learn more about recursive CTEs see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
ID, count(previous_id) 
from 
applications 
where 
previous_id is not null group by id ---record is not new
UNION
Select 
ID,0 
from 
applications 
where 
previous_id is null--when the record is new and does not have any revisions

select 
a.id, comments 
from 
applications a join comments c on a.id=c.id
order by 
C.id
```